# git remote rejected - local repositories

Tags: git, git-push, git-clone

If I have directory1 which contains a selection of files and which is under git control, and I run ..

```
git clone -l $HOME/directory1 directory2
```

I now have a copy of directory1 in my cwd.

If I then edit a file in directory2, add it to staging and commit it, I cannot push it to directory1 as I get the error..

```
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
```

I don't understand this, as the remote branch (directory1) is up-to-date and I did not alter it between cloning it to directory2 and trying to push it back to directory1.

EDIT: if I run `git status` inside  directory2, it says 'your branch is ahead of origin/master by 1 commit'.

I still don't get it.

Comment: Have you tried pulling first before pushing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remote%3A+error%3A+refusing+to+update+checked+out+branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're seeing is because the repository in `directory1` contains a *working copy* where `master` is the currently checked out branch.

At this point, you have two choices:

1. Turn the repo in `directory1` into a [bare repository](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefbarerepositoryabarerepository) (i.e. a repository without a working copy)
2. Tell Git to update the working copy in `directory1` when you push from `directory2` by setting the [`receive.denyCurrentBranch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-receivedenyCurrentBranch) option to `updateInstead`:

   ```
   cd directory1
   git config receive.denyCurrentBranch updateInstead
   ```

You can read more about this option in the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-receivedenyCurrentBranch):

> If set to `true` or `refuse`, `git-receive-pack` will deny a ref update to the currently checked out branch of a non-bare repository. Such a push is potentially dangerous because it brings the HEAD out of sync with the index and working tree.

`refuse` is the default value, hence the error when you push. Regarding the `updateInstead` value:

> Another option is `updateInstead` which will update the working tree if pushing into the current branch.

If your goal is to keep `directory1` and `directory2` in sync, I'd say this is the preferable alternative. However, keep in mind that:

> By default, `updateInstead` will refuse the push if the working tree or the index have any difference from the HEAD.

Which means that if you have uncommitted changes in `directory1`, a push from `directory2` will fail since it would overwrite whatever is in the index and the working copy.